# Android widget button press

Tags: android, widget

I’m developing my first widget and it is a simple calculator widget. I got the calculator widget showing up on the screen fine. But my problem is that I don’t know how handle buttons presses. E.g. if button 1 pressed, a textView changes to show 1. I got the calculator working as an app but not as a widget. I have some thing like:

RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);

```
final Intent onClickIntent = new Intent(context, CalculatorReceiver.class); 
    final PendingIntent onClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            onClickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    v.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.one, onClickPendingIntent);
```

Honestly, I don’t know what i’m doing here, but I want to recognize the click of button 1 and change the textView to 1, I don’t know where to perform this task. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you should put your full code up so people will be able to guide you

Comment: Simply, how would u do implement a code when a widget button clicked?

Comment: Onclicklistener for each button I guess